# Need help designing a website for phrase search in a bunch of text files

Tags: html, jsp, search, web-applications

You enter a line that you want to look up and it gives you matching results with some context i.e. a few lines above and below it.

I was wondering what would be the best way to do that.

The text files probably wouldn't go over a megabyte each and their total number would be about 200.

One method could be to store them as text files, read them in into memory with Java, do text searches and serve the results through JSP.

I don't have much knowledge of JSP and could always learn it but I believe it might be too slow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a search engine. There are many but most populars are ElasticSearch and Solr, which both use the Lucene Java library. Your requirement is very simple for a search system and both will do great job, but I'd choose ElasticSearch myself. You can also choose to use Lucene directly.

The feature to return results "with context" is called [highlighting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) in Eleasticsearch.

It seems your data is near 200megabytes, but if it was smaller you could also use a javascript implementation like [Lunr](http://lunrjs.com/)